# PHP SQL Datetime issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, time

I have a DATETIME field within a SQL table and retrieve the data accordingly - when trying to use the date_diff function however I receive the following message:

```
Message: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given
```

is there a way to convert the string I have taken from the SQL DB back into a date/time, the field format is as follows:

```
Y    -M -D H -M -S   
2014-02-15 14:55:29
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: If you show the SQL query, you can probably do the date diff in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the datetime string to `date_diff()` but that function expects a `DateTime()` object. You need to create a `DateTime()` object with the date first, then use `date_diff()`.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-02-15 14:55:29');
$date2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2014-02-15 14:55:29');
```

Comment: createFromFormat is unecessary as that date format is readable by DateTime()